# Are all responses from Google form text questions strings?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

sorry if this is a silly question. I have a form to collect orders from customers, and would like to send them an email (on form submission) detailing how much to transfer to my bank account. Will e.namedValues['Number of shirts'][0] be an integer value that I can manipulate and then include in the email body through the .toString() function?

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var name = e.namedValues['Name'][0];
  var email = e.namedValues['Email'][0];
  var shirts = e.namedValues['Number of Shirts'][0];
  var cost = shirts*25; \\$25 per shirt
  sendEmail_(name,email,shirts,cost);
}
```

Comment: Hi jh4, Could you please provide some code snippet we will able relate to?

Comment: You can test for the type of data assigned to a variable with `type of`  example:  `var dollarValue;   dollarValue = e.namedValues['Number of shirts'][0];  if (type of dollarValue === 'number') {dollarValue = dollarValue.toString()};`  [Data Type information](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp)

Comment: @Eugene I've added in the code. sendEmail_ is a function that creates the email detailing the number of shirts ordered and cost to the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submitted fields from a Google Form are stings, even if you have the validation type set to `Number`.

You will need to explicitly cast the string to a number before performing math operations on it. You can do this with `Number()` or `parseInt()`

Your revised code:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var name = e.namedValues['Name'][0];
  var email = e.namedValues['Email'][0];
  var shirts = Number(e.namedValues['Number of Shirts'][0]);
  var cost = shirts*25; \\$25 per shirt
  sendEmail_(name,email,shirts,cost);
}
```

In the future, you can test this be using `typeof` to determine the type of a variable. Such as:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(typeof e.namedValues['Number of Shirts'][0]);
}
```

It's also good to note that if you are appending a number to a string, or including a number in a string field. You do not need to cast it to a string with `toString()`. This will be performed implicitly.

Comment: thank you! Can I clarify that if I want to print "Thank you for ordering 5 tshirts" I could use 'Thank you for ordering '+5+'tshirts' ?